# How to calculate the particle derivative of the principal value of this integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

I'm reading the book Mathematical Physics, and here's a problem I couldn't figure out.

Let $\varphi(x)$ be a test function, show that

### \begin{equation}\frac{d}{dt}\{P \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{(x-t)}d x\}=P\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(t)}{(x-t)^2}\ dx.\end{equation}

The problem is, the only thing I know about principle value is that 
$$P(\frac{1}{x}):=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{x^2+\epsilon^2}=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&0,\quad x=0,\\
&\frac{1}{x}, \quad x\neq 0.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
So I'm not sure what the principal value here actually means.

Thanks in advance for whoever could give me some advice.

Cheers!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78845/taking-the-derivative-under-a-principal-value-integral?rq=1

Comment: Thank you so much @MariuszIwaniuk   But it must be that I don't have good technique in searching. I wonder how do you judge if there's already a similar question!   Thank you.