# Confusions when differentiating a Fourier Transform and using the Kramers-Kronig relations

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Let $x(t)$ be a real-valued squared-integrable signal that have a beginning and an ending time (so, is of finite duration). Then I will have that its Fourier Transform:
$$X(w) = U(w)+iV(w)$$
with $\{U(w),\ V(w)\}\in\mathbb{R}$ is such that:

- $X(w)$ is analytic
- $U(-w) = U(w)$
- $V(-w) = -V(w)$
- [Kramers–Kronig relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations):
  $U(w) = \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{2}\,\text{P.V.}\!\!\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{V(\xi)}{\xi-w}d\xi}$ and $V(w) = \displaystyle{-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\text{P.V.}\!\!\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{U(\xi)}{\xi-w}d\xi}$

Now, since differentiating the Fourier Transform goes at follow: $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial X(w)}{\partial w}=iw X(w)} \equiv iwU(w)-wV(w)\tag{Prop. 1}$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial X(w)}{\partial w}\; \overset{\text{linearity of}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial w}}{=}\; \frac{\partial U(w)}{\partial w}+i\frac{\partial V(w)}{\partial w} \overset{\text{Prop. 1}}{\equiv} iwU(w)-wV(w)$$
so by pairing the real and imaginary parts:

- $\frac{\partial U(w)}{\partial w} = -wV(w) \tag{Eq. 1}$
- $\frac{\partial V(w)}{\partial w} = wU(w) \tag{Eq. 2}$

Then, for example for the first one, I will have:
$$V(w) = -\frac{1}{w}\frac{\partial U(w)}{\partial w} = -\frac{1}{w}\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\,\text{P.V.}\!\!\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{V(\xi)}{\xi-w}d\xi\right) \tag{Eq. 3}$$

but I don't know how to differentiate $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\text{P.V.}\!\!\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{V(\xi)}{\xi-w}d\xi\right)$: if I use [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5B+int_%7B-inf%7D%5E%7Binf%7D+V%28x%29%2F%28x-w%29dx%2Cw%5D) it says that:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{V(\xi)}{\xi-w}d\xi\right)= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{V(\xi)}{(\xi-w)^2}d\xi$$
bit I am not sure if its right because the [Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) implies is a complex integral.

1. **How to differentiate $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\,\text{P.V.}\!\!\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{V(\xi)}{\xi-w}d\xi\right)$?**
2. **Does $\text{Eq. 3}$ set an equation to find a restricted form for $V(w)$ as a function of $w$? or it just will end in something like $V(w)=V(w)$? It is possible to solve this equation for $V(w)$?**
3. **Does the equations $\text{Eq. 1}$ and $\text{Eq. 2}$ behave as similar restrictions as the [Cauchy–Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)?**

As example, taking the second derivative of $X(w)$:
$$\frac{\partial^2 X(w)}{\partial w^2} = (iw)^2X(w) = -w^2X(w) = -w^2U(w)-iw^2V(w) \tag{Eq. 4}$$

But if I use $\text{Eq. 1}$ and $\text{Eq. 2}$, by differentiating them I will have:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 U(w)}{\partial w^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\frac{\partial U(w)}{\partial w}\right) \overset{\text{Eq. 1}}{=}  \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(-wV(w)\right) =-V(w)-w\frac{\partial V(w)}{\partial w}  \overset{\text{Eq. 2}}{=} -w^2U(w)-V(w) \tag{Eq. 5} $$

$$\frac{\partial^2 V(w)}{\partial w^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\frac{\partial V(w)}{\partial w}\right) \overset{\text{Eq. 2}}{=} \frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\; wU(w)\right) = \; U(w)+w \frac{\partial U(w)}{\partial w} \overset{\text{Eq. 1}}{=} -w^2V(w) +U(w) \tag{Eq. 6}$$

Now since,
$$\begin{array}{r c l}
\displaystyle{\frac{\partial^2 X(w)}{\partial w^2}} & = & \displaystyle{\frac{\partial^2 U(w)}{\partial w^2}+i\frac{\partial^2 V(w)}{\partial w^2}} \\
& \overset{\text{Eq. 5 & Eq. 6}}{=} & -w^2U(w)-V(w)+i\left(-w^2V(w) +U(w)\right) \\
& = & -w^2U(w)-iw^2V(w)+i\left(U(w) +iV(w)\right) \\
& = & -w^2X(w)+iX(w) = (i-w^2)X(w) \\
& \neq & \text{Eq. 4}
\end{array}$$

**Since I found a contradiction, please explain where and why I am making the mistake.**

---

*Added later___________________*

I found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/120700/909869) that:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left(\text{P.V.}\!\!\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{V(\xi)}{\xi-w}d\xi\right)= \text{P.V.}\!\!\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{V(\xi)-V(w)}{(\xi-w)^2}d\xi$$
so it somehow solves point $(1)$, but I still don't know if and how to use it to make a differential equation for $V(w)$, so it still missing an answer  for point $(2)$.

About the mentioned differential equation, I believe that the matching of $\text{Eq. 1}$ and $\text{Eq. 2}$ is an illegal operation, which leads to the contradiction, but I still don't know why and I would like to know were I am making a conceptual mistake... my intuition tells me is related with something about non-uniqueness of the complex derivative when Cauchy-Riemann Equations aren't hold: I believe this is the case of the Fourier Transform where only the imaginary axis is considered.

As example, following $\text{Eq. 1}$ and $\text{Eq. 2}$ I can make the following differential equations:
$$\begin{array}{l}
V''-\frac{V'}{w}+w^2V=0\\
U''-\frac{U'}{w}+w^2U=0\\
\Rightarrow y''-\frac{y'}{w}+w^2y=0 \Rightarrow y(w) = c_1\cos\left(\frac{w^2}{2}\right)+c_2\sin\left(\frac{w^2}{2}\right)
\end{array}$$
where not just imply that $U \equiv V$ which is false, but also the solution is an even function which don't fulfill the properties of $V(w)$ which is odd - an also is a fixed solution when the transform can have multiple values.

The problem I think is that the transform $X(w)$ which is related to any function (so it could take many forms), cannot be considered as a function in their differentiation property:

$$\frac{\partial X(w)}{\partial w} = iw X(w) \overset{\text{as function}}{\Rightarrow} X'(w)-iwX(w)=0 \Rightarrow X(w)=X(0)e^{i\frac{w^2}{2}}=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)dt\ e^{i\frac{w^2}{2}}$$
which is a fixed functions differently from the transform, so it is a conceptual mistake, but I would like to know why it don't work: **Does it imply is not possible to make a differential equation for $V(w)$?**

As example using the Kramer-Kronig relation an $\text{Eq. 2}$:
$$V(w) = \displaystyle{-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\text{P.V.}\!\!\!\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\xi(\xi-w)}\cdot\frac{\partial V(\xi)}{\partial \xi}\,d\xi}$$

**Is this conceptually wrong? Does having a differential equation fix the solution so is not applicable in the transforms framework?**

My guess is $\frac{\partial X(w)}{\partial w} \neq \frac{\partial U(w)}{\partial w}+i\frac{\partial V(w)}{\partial w}$ but I don't know why is not plausible, since the derivative is a linear operator.

Comment: There are some papers by Hardy on the differentiation of principal value integrals

Comment: @FShrike thanks for commenting. I have found this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s1-35.1.81)... this is what you were thinking about?... I don't understand it enough to use it, but in the spirit the question is to find the differential equation $V(w)$ is fulfilling to hold the Kramers-Kronig relation.... hope you can elaborate into this.

Comment: I don't know the right analysis to help answer your question. Hardy's paper and my upvote is the best I can do...

Comment: I'm not so sure about $X'=U'+iV'$. $X$ is complex differentiable, but $U$ and $V$ are not

Comment: Hi @CalvinKhor,  thanks for commenting. I was expecting answers fast since surely I am mistaken, but looks like is not so obvious were it is wrong. Converserly, I think the problem is that $X'$ is **not complex differentiable**, otherwise it will imply that $U$ and $V$ must be harmonic functions ($\nabla^2 U=0$ and $\nabla^2V=0$) and is not necessarily the case: but the issue with this analysis is that if the complex variable is $z= \sigma +iw$, in the Fourier transform $\sigma \equiv 0$ so I don't even know if the Cauchy-Riemann conditions apply or not.

Comment: No, $X’$ is definitely complex diff, this is because $x$ is compactly supported; this is the Paley Wiener theorem. So $U,V$ are harmonic. But they are definitely not complex differentiable (they are not open maps)

Comment: Maybe if you pretend you have the formula for $X$, eg $X(w)=w$ then you can understand what went wrong. Then the real part $U(w)=\Re w$ which has a gradient but not a complex derivative. Also, you have used $X’=iwX$ but this is not true. What is true is that $ \mathcal F (x’) = iw X$.  ($x’$ is interpreted distributionally)

Comment: @CalvinKhor that is my mistake!... I am confusing $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\mathit{F}\{x(t)\}(w)$ with $\mathit{F}\left\{\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}\right\}(w)$... thanks you very much.

Comment: Glad to help! @Joako Also the earlier bit about not being complex differentiable, I think that's not an issue as long as you restrict to real values of $w$. But you'll need to be careful if you want to use results from complex analysis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is just for closing the question, since the answer was given by @CalvinKhor as a comment.

All the issue is due I have confused the derivative of the Fourier Transform $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\mathbb{F}\{x(t)\}(w)$ with the Fourier Transform of the derivative $\mathbb{F}\{\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}\}(w)=iw \mathbb{F}\{x(t)\}(w)$.